# Log the individual items of an array with a for loop with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have this code which I was using to learn more about updating objects in javascript. This code was supposed to update the name of gabe from Paolo to Gabriel and it works well but I thought that in the for loop, I was going to get each individual key value, instead I get the object and see that the updates are made.

My question is how do I print the values of each key in the console using the for loop? Here is the code:

```
var gabriel = {
  firstName: "Paolo",
  lastName: "Avila"
}

console.log(gabriel.firstName + " " + gabriel.lastName);

gabriel.nickName = "Cai Cai";
gabriel.firstName = "Gabriel";

var gabe = [gabriel];

for(var i = 0; i < gabe.length; i++){
  console.log(gabe[i]);
}
```

I currently get this in the console:

```
Object {firstName: "Gabriel", lastName: "Avila", nickName: "Cai Cai"}
```

How do I get it to print just: `firstName: "Gabriel", lastName: "Avila", nickName: "Cai Cai"`.

TIA!

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(gabe[i]))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript can be access like arrays. Here's an example of doing this:

```
var gabriel = {firstName: "Gabriel", lastName: "Avila", nickName: "Cai Cai"};
for (var i in gabriel) { console.log(i+" - "+gabriel[i]); }
```

This outputs the following:

```
firstName - Gabriel
lastName - Avila
nickName - Cai Cai
```

In this case, within the loop the variable `i` will give you the property's name within the object.

Comment: Okay, so I needed a for in loop. I completely forgot about that! Thanks!

Comment: As I was writing the comment, I realized--I don't know how to merge your code with mine. I tried:

`var j = gabe;`

but that didn't work. How could I execute your code with mine?

Comment: I just made an edit to the code that may help you integrate better. You don't need to make another instance of the variable `gabriel` or try to cast it as an array. A for...in loops works well for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using regex and JSON.stringify, could be:

```js
var gabriel = {
  firstName: "Paolo",
  lastName: "Avila"
}

document.write('<p>' + gabriel.firstName + " " + gabriel.lastName + '</p>');

gabriel.nickName = "Cai Cai";
gabriel.firstName = "Gabriel";

var gabe = [gabriel];

for(var i = 0; i < gabe.length; i++) {
  var str = JSON.stringify(gabe[i]).replace(/^{(.*)}$/, '$1')
                .replace(/"([A-Za-z0-9_]+)"\:/g, '$1: ').replace('",', '", ');
  document.write('<p>' + str + '</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few different ways to achieve the same end.

You could implement `.toString` on your items:

```
var foo = {
    bar : "moo",
    woo : "miaow",
    toString : function(){
        return "bar : " + this.bar + ", woo : " + this.woo;
    }
}
```

or, my favourite, use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) combined with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
Object.keys(foo).map(function(k){ return k + " : " + foo[k]; }).join(", ");
```